# Firebase Emulator: Admin SDK not working for Firestore

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, fastapi, firebase-tools

I am running a FastAPI backend application that saves data on Firestore. I would like to test using a test database, and want to use the Firebase Emulator Suite. My code is as follows:

```
from google.cloud import firestore
import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

cred = credentials.Certificate(
    "my-project-firebase-adminsdk.json"
)
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app()

db = firestore.Client()
doc_ref = db.collection("business").document()
doc_ref.set({"name":"test"})
```

I have set the `FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST`,as instructed here (https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_firestore#admin_sdks) in my '.env' file, and can confirm the environment variables are loaded in.

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="my-project.json"
FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST="127.0.0.1:8080"
GCLOUD_PROJECT="my-project"
```

I have other GCP services (i.e. SecretManager), so I got service account credentials from GCP IAM.

I run the emulator just fine, and when I try to write data to the local Firestore instance, it gives me the following error in `firestore-debug.log` file:
`Multiple projectIds are not recommended in single project mode. Requested project ID google-cloud-firestore-emulator, but the emulator is configured for my-project. To opt-out of single project mode add/set the '"singleProjectMode": false' property in the firebase.json emulators config.`

I don't have the project `google-cloud-firestore-emulator` anywhere in my files. I have initialized firebase and the default project. The output of `firebase use` shows:

```
Active Project: my-project

Project aliases for /user/code/dir:

* default (my-project)

Run firebase use --add to define a new project alias.
```

I can confirm that `default_app` has the right project of `my-project`:
[image: Firebase App]

However, for some reason, the `db` has the project of `google-cloud-firestore-emulator`.
[image: Firestore Client]

I'm guessing it is because of this discrepancy that I am getting the error message and am unable to write data to the Firestore Emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realized that I needed to define the project within the Firestore Client instance.

```
db = firestore.Client("my-project")
```

I guess that if you specify:

```
FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST="127.0.0.1:8080"
```

Then the client will default the project to `google-cloud-firestore-emulator` and you have to respecify it.